# Hunchentoot (easy-routes) routes showing up in separate project?

Tags: routes, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I have two separate asdf systems/defprojects. Both of them use hunchentoot and easy-routes.

I put my code at the end but here is a quick summary:

`Project 1`
Port - 8000 || Document root: .../sending-app/web/ || HTML Page: admin.html

`Project 2`
Port - 9000 || Document root - .../sales-web/web/ || HTML Page: admin.html

They have the same route names and paths  (`/admin`) but different ports and different projects.

However, when i run `start-server2` while in project two, the routes from project 1 is active. Any change made to `/sending-app/web/admin.html` is not reflected even though the port is `9000`.

What do you think may be the issue?

#### Project 1:

```lisp
(in-package :project-one)

;; ==== Server Setup ==== ;;
(defvar *server* nil)

(defvar *document* "/Users/vince/quicklisp/local-projects/sending-app/web/")

(defun start-server2 ()
  (start (setf *server* (make-instance 'easy-routes-acceptor
                       :document-root *document*
                       :port 8000))))
(defun stop-server ()
  (when *server*
    (stop *server*)
    (start-server2)))

;; ==== Djula Setup ==== ;;

(djula:add-template-directory *document*)

(defparameter *admin.html* (compile-template* "admin.html"))

(defroute admin ("/admin" :method :get) ()
  (render-template* *admin.html* nil
            :title "Project 2"))
```

#### project 2:

```lisp
(in-package :project-two)

;; ==== Server Setup ==== ;;
(defvar *server* nil)

(defvar *document* "/Users/vince/quicklisp/local-projects/sales-web/web/")

(defun start-server2 ()
  (start (setf *server* (make-instance 'easy-routes-acceptor
                       :document-root *document*
                       :port 9000))))
(defun stop-server ()
  (when *server*
    (stop *server*)
    (start-server2)))

;; ==== Djula Setup ==== ;;

(djula:add-template-directory *document*)

(defparameter *admin.html* (compile-template* "admin.html"))

(defroute admin ("/admin" :method :get) ()
  (render-template* *admin.html* nil
            :title "Project 2"))
```

Comment: do packages share any symbols between them, in particular special variables like `*document*`?

Comment: https://github.com/mmontone/easy-routes#routes-for-individual-acceptors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes are registered globally by default, you can add an `:acceptor-name` argument to `defroute` to make a route local to an acceptor. From the [README](https://github.com/mmontone/easy-routes#routes-for-individual-acceptors):

> First you need to give your acceptor a name, using `:name` acceptor
> parameter:
>
> ```
> (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'easy-routes:routes-acceptor :name
> 'my-service))
> ```
>
> Then, use that name in routes definition `:acceptor-name`:
>
> ```
> (defroute my-route ("/my-route" :acceptor-name my-service)   ... )
> ```

You can also define a local macro `defroute*` that expands to `defroute` with your preferred acceptor name in both projects.

Comment: I see. When you say 'Routes are registered globally by default' that also means routes are register across projects too -- right?

Comment: @Self_Built Yes that's the case there is a central place where routes are stored that is the same for all projects (except you associate them with acceptor names)